# Copy multiple files into multiple folders using genrule in bazel

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bazel, cp

I would like to copy some files to specific directories.

Example:

I have some files structured like this

```
/scripts
    build.js
    test.js
    start.js
/config
    env.js
    path.js
```

How do you copy files under the scripts folder into a folder called scripts and files under the config folder into another folder called config.

```
#BUILD.bazel
filegroup(
  name="react-test",
  srcs=glob([
      "scripts/**/*.js", 
      "config/**/*"
  ])
)

#Macro
def copy_gen(name):
  native.genrule(
    name = name,
    srcs = ["//:react-test"],
    outs = ["scripts", "config"],
    cmd = "cp $SRCS @D", # What exactly do I do? Tried all sort
    output_to_bindir = 1,
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? What's happening vs. what are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 3):

Now I can solve this.

```
#BUILD.bazel

filegroup(
  name="react-test",
  srcs=[
      "react-test" #folder to copy
  ]
)
genrule(
    name = "copy",
    srcs = [":react-test"],
    outs = ["react-test"],
    cmd = "cp -r $(SRCS) $(OUTS)"
)
```